# How do I replace a match with a variable in rust?

Tags: regex, rust

This piece of code replaces "World" with "London":

```
fn replace_with(foo: &str) -> String {
    use regex::Regex;
    let before = "Hello, World";
    let re = Regex::new(r"(.*?)(World)").unwrap();
    String::from(re.replace_all(before, "$1 London"))
}
```

I'd instead like to replace it with `foo`. How do I do that? I've tried using "$foo" or "${foo}" and that doesn't work.

Comment: Take a quick trip to [the documentation](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace) which has a number of methods you can use. If you want to use named placeholders you have to, not surprisingly, name the placeholder. There's an example there that explains.

Comment: I'm not trying to use named placehoders. I'm trying to use the variable foo as a replacement, which is passed to my function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

```rust
format!("{} London", foo)`
```

In modern Rust (1.58+):

```rust
format!("{foo} London")
```

That's the closest you can get to JavaScript template strings and the `${x}` format.<sup>1</sup>

Where that's the argument to your substitution, as in `replace_all(before, format!(...))`.

--

<sup>1</sup>  In Rust it's more limited, you can't get as adventurous with arrays and such, just simple variable names. `{x[y]}` is not a valid substitution, for example.

Comment: You probably meant `format!("$1 {foo})`…